# iPHONE: QR CODE GENERATION

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement to generate a QR code image which will return a string when scanned. I have completed the scanning of QR code.I need some suggestion on how to generate a QR IMAGE in Iphone.

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Hahahahahaa! That's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Two different libraries that could be used:

- http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html
- https://github.com/zxing/zxing